# ResultSet.getInt() ERROR

Tags: java, mysql

so I'm trying to connect to a database using java.. there's a problem at a function I wrote getOutSymptoms.

Here's the code

```
package database_console;

import java.sql.*;

public class DBConnect {

private  Connection con;
private  Statement st;
private ResultSet rs;

public DBConnect(){

    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");


            try {
                con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/users", "root", "admin");
                st = con.createStatement();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }




    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public int getOutSymptoms(int userID) throws SQLException{
String query = "SELECT `user`.`out_symptoms` FROM user WHERE (`user`.`id` =" + userID + ")";

rs = st.executeQuery(query);
int out_symptoms_value = rs.getInt("out_symptoms");
st.close();
return out_symptoms_value;

}
```

the error is at the `getOutSymptoms` function, at the line:

```
int out_symptoms_value = rs.getInt("out_symptoms");
```

why is that? and how can I fix it?

thank u so much.

Comment: *What* error? Saying "the error" without giving us any indication of whether it's a compile-time error or an exception, or what the result is, is like going to the doctor and expecting them to diagnose what's wrong without describing the symptoms.

Answer (score 3):

You need to iterate through your result set in order to get the returned rows. When you first get your new ResultSet, it's not pointing to any particular row (its pointer is set to a row before first) and you need to call `rs.next()` method at least once to get to the actual results.

If you know there can be only one result you can do something like this:

```
if (rs.next()) {
   int out_symptoms_value = rs.getInt("out_symptoms");
   //do other stuff
} else {
   //query returned no results
}
```

If you expect to have more than one row returned, then you can do this:

```
while(rs.next()) {
  int out_symptoms_value = rs.getInt("out_symptoms");
  //do the rest of processing
}
```

**TLDR**: You need to call `rs.next()` at least once to get to the actual results.

Comment: @user3818372 u r welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

In order to start using a ResultSet, you must call the next() method. Although you haven't stated the exact error, you will definitely run into this problem unless it is added before you call getInt().

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/retrieving.html

Answer (score 0):

you need to iterate through the resultSet object using `rs.next()` to get the value. resultSet doesn't point to the actual row but when you call `rs.next()` it points to first result.

```
while(rs.next(){
 int d = rs.getInt("  ");
}
```

`rs.next()` returns a boolean value , incase nothing is returned the loop will not execute & you will not get an Exception at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

You have already passed the database name in connection string so change this

```
String query = "SELECT `user`.`out_symptoms` FROM user WHERE (`user`.`id` =" + userID + ")";
```

to

```
String query = "SELECT out_symptoms FROM tableName WHERE id =" + userID;
```

Then just iterate over the obtained ResultSet like this

```
while(rs.next()) {
  int out_symptoms_value = rs.getInt("out_symptoms");

}
```

Moreover its good to use `PreparedStatement` instead of `Statement` which cna prevent you from sql injection